# Malloced pointer changes value on return

Tags: c

I have code that looks like this :

```
Foo* create(args) {
    Foo *t = malloc (sizeof (Foo)) ;
    // Fill up fields in struct t from args. 
    return t;
}
```

The call is

```
Foo *created = create (args)
```

Note that the function and the call to the function are two separate modules. 
The value of the pointer assigned to `t` on being `malloc`ed is slightly different to what is captured in `created`.  Seemingly the MSB of the address is changed and replaced with `fffff`.  The LSB portion is the same for around 6-7 characters.

I'm at a loss as to what's going on. 
I'm using GCC 4.6

Comment: Can you please include all relevant code, specifically the code you are using to print the pointer, both in create and out of it.

Comment: Likely to be 32/64 bit issue. Possibly same or similar issue to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094133/memccpy-return-lower-memory-address-than-the-src-starting-address#comment50204886_31094133. But we can't tell just from the info you have provided.

Comment: Do you see any warnings when you compile with the -Wall flag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most likely explanation one can come up with from what you provided is that at the point of the call the function `create` is *undeclared*. A permissive C compiler assumed that unknown function `create` returned an `int` and generated code, which effectively truncated the pointer value or, more precisely, sign-extended the assumed `int` return value into the MSB of the recipient pointer (assuming a platform where pointers are wider than `int` in terms of their bit-width, e.g. 64-bit platform).

Most likely the compiler issued a warning about an undeclared function being called, but the warning was ignored by the user.

Make sure declaration (or, better, prototype) of `create` is visible at the point of the call. If you are compiling in C99 mode (or later), ask your compiler to strictly enforce C99 requirements. And don't ignore compiler diagnostic messages.

Comment: That diagnosis was super accurate. This is EXACTLY what happened.  The build system prints out so much stuff on screen, I missed the warning for implicit declaration.